# Editing files directly in Heroku

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to edit files directly in Heroku? It's very uncomfortable to push serveral commits and run `heroku logs --tail` and this command doesn't display readable resons on the errors.

Comment: Did you read https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec?

Comment: It's far more work than it is actually worth. When deploying your code it is based on Heroku-20 which is based on Ubuntu 20.04. I'd rather deploy a fresh VPS and test your stuff there.